# Java line of code on DFA

Tags: java, finite-automata

I've recently been studying Deterministic Finite-Automata in class, and I've come a across a piece of code from princeton.edu that simply explains it on java. Problem is I'm not really well versed in java and I would like to ask what the line  int[][] next = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 0 } }; in the code does.

I seem to understand how the over all code works. But I can't really understand what the line int[][] next = { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 0 } }; specifically does. This seems to be basic java. can some one please enlighten me? thanks!

```
/*************************************************************************
*  Compilation:  javac DFA.java
*  Execution:    java DFA
*  
*  Simulate a DFA which recognizes the language of all strings over
*  the binary alphabet { a, b } with a multiple of three b's.
*
*  % java DFA babbabab
*  false
*
*  % java DFA babbaabbba
*  true
*
*************************************************************************/

public class DFA {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = args[0];
    boolean[] accept = { true, false, false };
    int[][] next = {               //<---   
                     { 0, 1 },     //<---  
                     { 1, 2 },     //<--- 
                     { 2, 0 }  };  //<--- 
    int state = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        state = next[state][input.charAt(i) - 'a'];
    }
    System.out.println(accept[state]);
}
}
```

for more info here's a link to the source: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/73dfa/

Comment: It is a two dimensional integer array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `next` variable references a 2-dimensional array containing the state transitions of the DFA.

The array has three rows, one for each state in the DFA.

The line below shows that the array members in a row are the next state for 'a' and 'b' respectively.

```
 state = next[state][input.charAt(i) - 'a']
```

The DFA is in state 0 only when the count of the number of b's is a multiple of 3. If it ends in state zero, this array says that the string is accepted.

```
boolean[] accept = { true, false, false };
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a multidimensional array in java.

Here is a quote from the oracle docs:

"In the Java programming language, a multidimensional array is an array whose components are themselves arrays"

```
class MultiDimArrayDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[][] names = {
        {"Mr. ", "Mrs. ", "Ms. "},
        {"Smith", "Jones"}
    };
    // Mr. Smith
    System.out.println(names[0][0] + names[1][0]);
    // Ms. Jones
    System.out.println(names[0][2] + names[1][1]);
}
```

}

The output from this program is:

Mr. Smith
Ms. Jones

This link may help clear it up for you:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

This line is declaring an array, where each element is a pair or integers. Technically, each element is an array of integers (an array of arrays) - in this particular case, the individual arrays each contain 2 elements.

In this example, it looks like the array is defining the state transitions, where the first element is the current state and the second element is the next state.